# Gutter brackets screwed through shingles

Tags: roof, gutters

I had a new roof and gutters installed last year, and while cleaning the gutters I noticed that while most of them are attached like the following picture
[image: good attachment]

there are a few that are attached by screwing a bracket through the shingle, as in this picture:

[image: screwed attachment]

Is this properly installed? It doesn't seem right to have anything exposed penetrating the shingle like this. If they're not, what should I do to remedy the situation?

Comment: To the contractor's credit, he did seem to use a sheet-metal roofing screw with a "washer" head that probably has a rubber gasket under there to help seal it, but no, that shouldn't have been installed like that.